# nohup process pid not visible in new shell but still in old shell

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, nohup

I open and connect an ssh terminal window shell to my server and run this:

```
nohup sleep 50000 &
```

When I then run `ps` I see this:

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:00 bash
   56 ?        00:00:00 sleep
  148 ?        00:00:00 ps
```

Now while I am still connected to first shell session and using same credentials as first session, I open up a second ssh terminal window shell to my server and run `ps` again and I see this:

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:00 bash
   86 ?        00:00:00 ps
```

How can I see the nohup processes that were started from the first shell session in the second shell session (assuming that I do NOT know the PID)? Or more generally, how can I see all nohup processes that are running that were started in other shells/sessions?

EDIT: Note that I also tried opening up a new shell/session with root user credentials and I still do not see the sleep process when using ps from here either.

Comment: Well long story short, I could seem to get this to work after trying things so I ended up setting up the script to run as a service so that makes sure it will always be running even after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `ps` from a different shell, you will see only processes initiated by that shell session even with root privileges. To see processes initiated by other users or in a different session, use option `-a` or `-e`. See [man ps](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html).

[image: scrot1]

[image: scrot2]

Comment: I tried both -a and -e but neither works... it still does not show anything from the other session.

Comment: @jsherk - I added 2 screenshots from my test on Debian 11. Second one is from a separate terminal I opened after closing the three first ones. Maybe you could edit your question to add similar screenshots?